# React - How can i extract values from a form and update my state?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am learning react and got stuck with this problem.

I have created a state for users with two properties **name** & **tweet** on my *App.js component* and *Tweet.js* component fetches the data from the state and outputs the tweet on the DOM.

I want to create a new user in my state when the form is submitted. How can i do so?

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Tweet from './Tweet';

function App () {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    {name:'Coulson', tweet:'Avengers Assemble'},
    {name:'Rick', tweet:'Living in world of dead.'},
    {name:'Barry', tweet:'I am the Flash.'},
    {name:'Judith', tweet:'Hi Carl.'},
    {name:'Michonne', tweet:'I have a katana.'},
    {name:'Bob', tweet:'Lets build something.'},
  ])

  return(
    <div className="App">
      <div className="form">
        <form>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label> <input type="text" />
          <label htmlFor="tweet">Tweet</label> <input type="text" />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

      </div>
      {users.map(user => (
          <Tweet name={user.name} tweet={user.tweet} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )

}

export default App;
```

Tweet.js

```
import React from 'react'
import "./App.css"

function Tweet ({name, tweet, likes}) {

    return(
        <div className="tweet">
            <h3>{name}</h3>
            <p>{tweet}</p>
            <h3>Likes: {likes}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tweet;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you probably want to maintain [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for your form to give you more control over what goes on in them and to access the form data more easily.

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [tweet, setTweet] = React.useState("");

  const handleChangeName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleChangeTweet = (e) => {
    setTweet(e.target.value);
  }

...

<label htmlFor="name">Name</label> 
<input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChangeName}/>
<label htmlFor="tweet">Tweet</label>
<input type="text" value={tweet} onChange={handleChangeTweet}/>
```

Then you'd need to write a submit handler function which is called when the form is submitted, inside which you can access the form data you've been tracking and update the users array:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newUser = { name, tweet };
    setUsers([...users, newUser])
  }
```

I made an example [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/WNNZLQj).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a handleSubmit() function

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //logic to populate state as you want
}
```

And call in that way

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```